# Unix tool to output first n characters in an UTF-8 encoded file

Tags: unix, shell, utf-8, text-processors, head

I want to print the first 1000 **characters** in an UTF-8 encoded file. I know that the *head* tool can print the first n bytes of a file, but it may cut a character in the middle so that I get garbled output at the end.

I can write a awk program to do this, but may I know if there is any simpler way?

PS. I found it unreasonable that *head* and *tail* do not support character encoding (the LANG environment variable), while other tools such as *cut*, *wc*, *sed* and *awk* all support character encoding.

Comment: One other thing to think about - even if you output whole code points, you may still end up separating base characters from their subsequent combining characters.  If that’s a problem for your application you’ll need to do something a bit more sophisticated than the answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is simpler, but this my way:

```
cat file | iconv -t UTF-32 | head -c $[1000 *4+4] | iconv -f UTF-32
```

This converts to a fixed-width form of Unicode so that the 1000 will always represent whole characters.

Comment: iconv (the one included in glibc) has a bug of buffering the whole input before making any output. This has a huge performance impact. Nevertheless, your approach works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the `awk` way that OP mentioned to other Googlers, let's test with 5 [acute accented vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent):

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
```

picks the first three characters and outputs the desired:

```
áéí
```

Each of those UTF-8 characters is 2 bytes long, we can check that with:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | hd
```

which gives:

```
00000000  c3 a1 c3 a9 c3 ad c3 b3  c3 ba                    |..........|
0000000a
```

so we could equivalently test it as:

```
printf '\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
```

If we use the wrong locale, e.g. `C` which treats each byte separately:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}' | hd
```

gives the first three bytes:

```
c3 a1 c3
```

which shows on the terminal as just:

```
á
```

since the `c3` is trash by itself.

Not sure how it compares to `iconv` in terms of performance for huge inputs. But for small stuff this is good enough and simple.

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04.